# Wrting A Movie app , must be a better way

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to get the value from the from and and pass it to the API and output the result to the DOM. The code works fine but I am 1000% sure there is a better way to write THIS. Thanks for the help and I am new so trying to learn.

### JS CODE

```js
const textInput = document.querySelector(`#search__box`);
const btn = document.querySelector(`#btn`);
const ShowName = document.querySelector(`.show__name`);
const btn_rest = document.querySelector(`.btn__reset`);
let btn__test = "";
const btnClickHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${userData}`).then((res) => {
        const looparr = res.data;
        try {
            for (show of looparr) {
                const createDiv = document.createElement(`div`);
                const createA = document.createElement(`p`);
                const createIMG = document.createElement(`img`);
                const createH3 = document.createElement(`h3`);
                const createH4 = document.createElement(`h4`);
                createDiv.classList.add(`yes`);
                createIMG.classList.add(`img-style`);
                createH3.innerHTML = show.show.summary;
                createIMG.src = show.show.image.medium;
                createH4.innerText = `Release Year ${show.show.premiered}`;
                ShowName.append(createDiv);
                createDiv.append(createA);
                createDiv.append(createIMG);
                createDiv.append(createH3);
                createDiv.append(createH4);
                createDiv.style.borderBottom = `1px solid black`;
                createA.classList.add(`test`);
                createA.innerText = show.show.name;

                btn__test = document.querySelectorAll(`.yes`);
            }
        } catch {
            (e) => {};
        }
    });
};

const btnResetHanddler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (div of btn__test) {
        ShowName.removeChild(div);
    }
    textInput.value = "";
};

const inputHanddler = (e) => {
    const test = e.target.value;
    return (userData = test);
};

btn.addEventListener(`click`, btnClickHandler);

textInput.addEventListener(`change`, inputHanddler);

btn_rest.addEventListener(`click`, btnResetHanddler);
```

```css
html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
    position: relative;
}


.search__wrapper{
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

#search__box{
    width: 30rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(213, 207, 207);
}

.show__name{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 2rem;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.show__name p {
    margin: 1.2rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.test{
    font-size: 40rem;
    color: black;
}

.img-style{
    transition: all 2s;
    width: 400px;
}

.img-style:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
margin-top: 1.5rem;}
    


 .yes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TV APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <section class="search__wrapper">
        <form action="#">
            <label for="search__box">search</label>
            <input type="search" name="search__box" id="search__box">
            <button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn__reset">Reset</button>
        </form>

        <ul class="list">

        </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="show__name">

    </section>



    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: With Javascript there is always "a better way."  But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some improvements I can suggest:

1. Use a linter for your CSS to ensure the formatting remains constant, it allows others to more easily assist you.

   For example, this portion would be automatically fixed on save:

   ```css
   .img-style:hover{
       transform: scale(1.1);
   margin-top: 1.5rem;}
   ```
2. Use a variable assignment when in JavaScript loops, otherwise you are creating a global variable which can have unintended consequences.

   So this:

   ```js
   for (show of looparr) {
   ```

   Would turn into this:

   ```js
   for (const show of looparr) {
   ```

   Since you do not need to change the value of the variable during your iterations.
3. Don't place `btn__test = document.querySelectorAll(".yes");` inside your upper loop, that will be called multiple times unnecessarily. Instead, place that segment within the `btnResetHanddler` function, where it is actually used.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. do you think there is a shorter way to write the same function?

Comment: I think what you have right now is good, it's clear and it gets the job done